# Trouble Trying to play a song from a playlist

Tags: java, android

Kind of a newbie here, but I am trying to create a music app for my project in Android Studio and I keep running into an error every time I try to play a song from my playlist.

Here's the error on Logcat

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.spectrumv1.Song.getId()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.spectrumv1.SongCollection.searchSongById(SongCollection.java:30)
    at com.example.spectrumv1.PlaySongActivity.handleSelection(PlaySongActivity.java:40)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574) 
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

And here are the two classes mentioned by Logcat with errors

SongCollection.java

```
public class  SongCollection {



    public Song[] songs = new Song[2];

    public SongCollection() {

        Song godSpeed = new Song(
                "S1001",
                "(1) Godspeed",
                "Frank Ocean",
                "https://p.scdn.co/mp3-preview/6548bf4d7ad5b17d7602528182e586b86db8e23b?cid=2afe87a64b0042dabf51f37318616965",
                2.97,
                "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273c5649add07ed3720be9d5526");

        songs[0] = godSpeed;

    }

    public Song getCurrentSong(int currentSongId) {
        return songs[currentSongId];
    }

    public int searchSongById(String Id) {
        for (int index = 0; index < songs.length; index++) {
            Song tempSong = songs[index];
            if (tempSong.getId().equals(Id)) {
                return index;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public int getNextSong(int currentSongIndex) {
        if (currentSongIndex >= songs.length - 1) {
            return currentSongIndex;
        } else {
            return currentSongIndex + 1;
        }
    }

    public int getPrevSong(int currentSongIndex) {
        if (currentSongIndex <= 0) {
            return currentSongIndex;
        } else {
            return currentSongIndex - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And PlaySongActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class PlaySongActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SongCollection songCollection = new SongCollection();
    static ArrayList<Song> playList = new ArrayList<Song>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_song);
        ImageButton S1001 = findViewById(R.id.songBG);
        Picasso.with(this).load(songCollection.songs[0].getCoverArt()).into(S1001);
    }


    public void sendDataToActivity(int index)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SongPlayer.class );
        intent.putExtra("index", index);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void handleSelection(View view)
    {
        String resourceId = getResources().getResourceEntryName(view.getId());
        int currentArrayIndex = songCollection.searchSongById(resourceId);
        Log.d("temasek", "the current array position is: " + currentArrayIndex);
        sendDataToActivity(currentArrayIndex);
    }

}
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think there's two issues causing your error. I think the first problem is that you created an array and didn't fill it with values

```
public Song[] songs = new Song[2];
...
Song godSpeed = new Song( ... )
songs[0] = godSpeed; // !! songs[1] isn't defined
```

And I think that `if (tempSong.getId().equals(Id))` must not be working as intended, which is causing it to miss the correct song (godSpeed in songs[0]) and check the undefined element ( songs[1] )

I would recommend some sort of logging to check if it's working correctly.